# Why does this error: "TypeError: _websocket_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.send is not a function" occur when the socket is imported?

Tags: redux, websocket, stomp

I'm new to react/redux, but I'm trying to use it to build a front-end that will interface with a back-end via RabbitMQ.  I have a websockets.js file where I establish my websocket and STOMP client:

```
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
var msgpack = require("msgpack-lite");

var onConn = () => {
  console.log('Successfully Connected');
  stompClient.subscribe('/queue/frontend-response', onMessage);
 //var params = { "params": "{}" };
 //var obj = JSON.stringify(msgpack.encode(params));
 //stompClient.send(
 //  '/exchange/product/product.request.find', 
 //  {'reply-to': 'frontend',  'correlation-id': 999}, 
 //  obj);
};

var onErr = (e) => {
  console.log('***************** Error:  ' + e);
};

function onMessage(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

var wss = new WebSocket("MY AMQP INSTANBCE");
var stompClient = Stomp.over(wss);
stompClient.connect(uname, pword, onConn, onErr, uname);

export default { stompClient };
```

If I uncomment the code in `onConn`, data gets sent and a response is received correctly.  However, I'd like for this socket to be importable by any component that needs to communicate with the back-end.  I have this in my `actions/index.js` file:

```
// src/js/actions/index.js
import stompClient from './websocket.js';
import { SET_PRODUCTS } from "../constants/action-types";

var msgpack = require("msgpack-lite");

export function setProducts(payload) {
  var params = { "params": "{}" };
  var obj = JSON.stringify(msgpack.encode(params));
  stompClient.send(
    '/exchange/product/product.request.find', 
    {'reply-to': 'frontend',  'correlation-id': 999}, 
    obj);
  return { type: SET_PRODUCTS, payload }
};
```

Currently, this code gets executed when a button is clicked in the UI.  Note that the code in `setProducts` is identical to the code that works in `websockets.js`.  But here I don't get any data back, I get the error mentioned in the title.

Can someone explain what's going on here and suggest a way I can make this work outside of my `websockets.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh...I changed `export default { stompClient };` to `export default stompClient;`, and it works.